# How do I get Angular 1.3 ngMessages to stop resizing my form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm very new to front-end design.  Basically I have a form and I would like to take advantage of ng-messages to show validation error messages when the user submits or leaves a field.  My form resizes to fit the inputs and the error messages and it looks bad. I know I'm not going to be able to word this the right way so bear with me. Ultimately I want the form to be sized properly on document ready.  And when a validation error happens, the form won't resize.. there will be spaces for the `ng-messages` to be built in, so the form doesn't grow or contract based on whether there are error messages or not.

Here are two screen shots from the plunker to show the expanding contracting form:

start up form size:

[image: start up form size]

after blurred out of both inputs:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any insight you all can shed.

here's a link to my plunkr: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKYURpuOR3qRoid1n7YO?p=preview)

Comment: So you want the input field to increase in size when an error appears?

Comment: No.  I'd like the input fields to stay the same size. I'd like the spaces between each input to stay the same, as if there were an error showing. (that way my form size stays constant -- assuming no page resizes)  But the error text would only display as necessary.

Comment: Essentially I'd like the form to be the size of the second image I posted.  But I'd only like the error messages to display if there's a problem.  I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 0):

So I found A solution.  I don't think it's THE solution.

Here's my html body:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="myclass">
        <form class="form" role="form" name="myform" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="newname" placeholder="Name" required/>
            <div ng-if="myform.name.$touched" ng-messages="myform.name.$error">
              <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="newemail" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <div ng-if="myform.email.$touched" ng-messages="myform.email.$error">
              <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
              <div ng-message="email">Not a valid email</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <p>User Entered: {{newname}}</p>
    <p>myform.name.$error = {{myform.name.$error | json}}</p>
    <p>form submitted = {{submitted}}</p>
  </body>
```

So I added some css markdown for `form-group` classes that looks like this:

```
body .container form .form-group {
  height: 50px;
}
```

this way the size of the form-group stays static and my form is not resizing based on whether or not I have error messages.

However... I really don't think this will work on mobile devices.  Have yet to test that. But if anybody has a more robust, smarter way of fixing the problem, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the `ng-if` on the `ng-message` divs you can add a conditional class to add `visibility: none` to the div when `$touched` is `false`. This way the div still takes up the space but it is hidden from view.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8SiZ5jyAQPolJGefhLER?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{'invisible': !myform.name.$touched}" ng-messages="myform.name.$error">
```

**CSS**

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```